# How to check for available space in Elasticsearch with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, memory

I am completely new to Python but I need make a script that will check the Elasticsearch disk space on AWS and return a warning if it is below a certain threshold. I imagine I would have to create a client instance of Elasticsearch, create a dictionary for the search query to search for space available? But I'm honestly not sure. I'm really hoping someone can provide a starter code syntax to kind of push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You use CloudWatch [metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics.html#managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics-cluster-metrics) for that, e.g.:

- `FreeStorageSpace`
- `ClusterUsedSpace`

Comment: I tried using this -- where I've filled in the domain name appropriately, but it did not work 
SELECT SUM(FreeStorageSpace) FROM 'AWS/ES' WHERE  DomainName = '<domain-name>'